# Can't find the correct pattern for Fnmatch in C (exclude a two digit number)

Tags: c, glob

I've been searching for a couple of days and I can't seem to find information on how to do this in C with fnmatch.

I'm trying to make a pattern that matches: xxxx00_xxx (x being any char, 00 being any number except 02).

So far all I've got is: **????[0-9][!2]_???**
The problem, as you can see, is that it's excluding any number ending with 2 (12, 22, etc). But I'm interested in all numbers except 02.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Fixed the tagging. That should help avoid some non-answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess it's not really a RegExp question, thanks for changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem with `fnmatch` patterns, you need two separate patterns, for instance:

```
????[!0]?_???
????0[!2]_???
```

I chose these to avoid the possibility of any string matching both patterns, so if you're making a list of matches (e.g. using the `glob` function) you should be able to just concatenate your lists.

Comment: So, there's really no way to do this in one pattern? That's too bad, I guess I'll have to check the glob function then. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you want to do it with a single pattern, you need regex. Regex is generally a lot more efficient if you'll be using the same pattern over and over to match different strings, anyway.

Comment: That's an option too, I didn't really know there was a regexp library in C, but I'll be trying that. Thanks again!

Comment: Neither `fnmatch` nor the regex functions are part of the standard library in *plain C*, but both are in POSIX, and thus available on any "unix-like" system. See `regcomp` and `regexec`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm working on a Unix-like system so it shouldn't be any problem. I'm still having a bit of trouble finding the right regular expression for the mentioned pattern, but I guess I need to keep trying.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. You've been a great help :-) . I think I can work it out from here. I wish I could give you an up-vote...